# No success action on refresh NGRX

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Im stuck with a problem. I'm loading some users into a mat-selection-list inside a form. The first time everything works fine, but when i try to refresh the page the selector returns 'undefiened'.

First time, both GET_USERS and GET_USERS_SUCCESS runs (and i see the console log message 'loadUserTest'), but when i refresh the page, only GET_USERS runs, but no success and no console message.

In other words, on refresh there must be a problem because the effect doesn't run..
The error message in console is *'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined'*, and that makes sense because the selector cant find any data.

Does anyone see what the problem might be?

**Actions**

```
/*--------------GetAllUsers--------------*/

export class GetUsers implements Action {
readonly type = ActionTypes.GET_USERS;
}

export class GetUsersSuccess implements Action {
readonly type = ActionTypes.GET_USERS_SUCCESS;

constructor(public payload: User[]) {}
}

export class GetUsersError implements Action {
readonly type = ActionTypes.GET_USERS_ERROR;

constructor(public payload: string) {}
}
```

**Effect**

```
@Effect()
loadUsers$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(usersActions.ActionTypes.GET_USERS),
switchMap(() => {
  console.log("loadUserTest");
  return (
    this.userResource.getUsers().pipe(
      map((users: User[]) => new usersActions.GetUsersSuccess(users)),
      catchError((err) => {
          console.log("errorTest");
          return of(new usersActions.GetUsersError(err)) }),
    )
  );
  })
);
```

**Reducer**

```
case usersActions.ActionTypes.GET_USERS_SUCCESS: {
  return adapter.addAll(action.payload, {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    loaded: true,
  });
}

case usersActions.ActionTypes.GET_USERS_ERROR: {
  return {
    ...state,
    entities: {},
    loading: false,
    loaded: false,
    error: action.payload,
  };
}
```

**Selector**

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AppState } from '../../../core/state';
import { adapter } from './users.adapter';

const { selectAll } = adapter.getSelectors();

export const selectState = (state: AppState) => state.user.users;

export const getUsers = createSelector(selectState, selectAll); //Problem!
```

**Create.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

this.createEventForm();
this.store$.dispatch(new fromUsers.GetUsers());
this.users$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromUsers.getUsers));
}
```

**Html**

```
<mat-selection-list class="form-group" #selectedUsers formControlName="users">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let user of users$ | async" [value]="user">
        {{ user.name }}
      </mat-list-option>
 </mat-selection-list>
```

Comment: can you show us how your `reducer` and its `initial state` looks like? I would say that the problem is  at this code part: `return adapter.addAll(action.payload, {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    loaded: true,
  });`
Edit: also show us your `ActionTypes.GET_USERS` from reducer

Comment: The problem was that @ngrx/store/update-reducers wiped out the state... I fixed it by adding a timeout before the dispatch, which seems like a not so good solution.. do you know if it's possible to check that @ngrx/store/update-reducers has been running before i do the dispatch?

Comment: Can you show me your code? Make minimal example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddbmtz

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the code you provided isn't enough to understand the issue.

I can advise two things:
check the effect and what it returns after `this.userResource.getUsers()` to be sure it's an array of users.

If the effect isn't triggered then the `.users` is mentioned only in

```
export const selectState = (state: AppState) => state.user.users;
```

try to debug it to be sure that the `state` has `user` with `users`.

```
export const selectState = (state: AppState) => {
  debugger;
  return state.user.users;
};
```

I assume the problem in one of these places.

Answer (score 0):

@CharlieV2, I had such a problem that I wanted to use effect from a featured store into another featured store and when the action triggered, the effect based on that action didn't work.

The solution worked for me was importing featured store's effect needed into the featured module I was working as follows:

```
EffectsModule.forFeature([featuredEffect, featuredEffectedNeeded!])
```